# Can't edit apache2.2 httpd.conf on Windows 7

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-7

I tried to edit httpd.conf but unfortunately the file appears to be in use by another process and so I can't save the changes even when I stop the apache process from the task menu.

Comment: Not making a full answer, because i'm not sure, but iirc, apache for windows runs in c:\Program files\ --- editing anything in there requires elevating your privledges.  Try running your text editor as an administrator ...

Answer (score 4):

Just like Jason said in his comment -- run the editor with Administrator's rights. I had the same problem. Right-clicked on my Notepad++ launcher, chose "Run as administrator", opened the file and off you go!

Comment: I'm running my editor as administrator but the issue persists!

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a necro, but I found this after a quick googling and wanted to help out any other weary netizens.

It's because the permissions are set to read only for the users group during the apache installer. To fix this. Rightclick the file, select properties. On the security tab, select users and click 'edit'. Then add write privileges to the users group.

Answer (score 1):

There's a good explanation for this problem, it's because of VirutalStore

http://blog.netscraps.com/bugs/apache-httpd-conf-changes-ignored-in-windows-7.html

Comment: Please don't just link to external sites, try to add something in the future.